# get 24 hours date and time for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one drop-down(values are "Last 24 hours", "Last 48 hours", etc like) when I select "Last 24 hours" in the drop-down
i need all dates from now to yesterday with one hour intervals.

i tried this,

```
   var todayDate = new Date();
    if(type=="hours"){ // for hours based drop-down
        var oneDayAgo = new Date(todayDate.getTime());
        oneDayAgo.setDate(todayDate.getDate() - 1);
        console.log("oneDayAgo"+oneDayAgo);
        var hours = todayDate.getHours();
        for(var i = hours; i <= hours+24; i++) {
            if(i<25){
                var newHours=i;
                var newDates=todayDate.getFullYear() + "-" + ("00" + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("00" + todayDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + ("00" +newHours).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + todayDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + todayDate.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
                console.log(newDates);
            }else{
                var newHours=i-24;
                var newDates=oneDayAgo.getFullYear() + "-" + ("00" + (oneDayAgo.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("00" + oneDayAgo.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + ("00" +newHours).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + oneDayAgo.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + oneDayAgo.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
                console.log(newDates);
            }
        }
    }
```

my expected output is ,

for example current date and time is 2014-04-27 13:07 means,

output like 2014-04-27 13:07, 2014-04-27 12:07, 2014-04-27 11:07 , 2014-04-27 10:07.... 2014-04-26 13:07

please help on this. thanks

Comment: Avoid creating variables in loops. Create them before and use them inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getDateItems(hours) {
  var toDate = new Date();
  var fromDate = new Date();
  fromDate.setTime(fromDate.getTime() - (hours * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var result = [];
  
  while (toDate >= fromDate) {
    result.push(toDate.getFullYear() + "-" + ("00" + (toDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("00" + toDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + ("00" + toDate.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + toDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + toDate.getSeconds()).slice(-2));
    // consider using moment.js library to format date
    
    toDate.setTime(toDate.getTime() - (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  }

  return result;
}

var datesFrom24Hours = getDateItems(24);
var datesFrom48Hours = getDateItems(48);

console.log(datesFrom24Hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a [working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/aw8rkncb/1/), which might be what you want.

```
//get type and hoursOption from dropdowns
var type = 'hours'
var hoursOption = 48;

var todayDate = new Date();

if(type=="hours"){ // for hours based drop-down

    var hours = todayDate.getHours();
    for(var i = hours; i <= hours + hoursOption; i++) {
            todayDate.setHours(todayDate.getHours() - 1)
        var newDates = todayDate.getFullYear() + "-" + ("00" + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("00" + todayDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + ("00" + todayDate.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + todayDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + todayDate.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
            console.log(newDates);

    }
}
```

For `for-loop` variable `hours` I added `hourOption` which comes from dropdown options, eg. 24, 48, 72, etc.

Inside loop you take `todayDate` and just add one hour less then before, so it will show hours counting backwards.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
const start = new Date("2022-01-01T00:00:00");
    const end = new Date("2022-01-01T23:00:00");
    
    for (let current = start; current <= end; current.setHours(current.getHours() + 1)) {
        console.log(current);
    }
```